# How can I find a word ending with "n't" before a number using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to find all "n't" in a sentence with this Regex `'n't [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?'`. And its working fine in [RegExr](https://regexr.com):

[image]

but When I try to do it with this code, it does not work:

```
txt = "japan isn't 56 country in Europe."
nt = re.findall(r"n't [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?",txt)
print(nt)
```

Comment: `re.findall(r"n't \d+",txt)` or `re.search(r"n't [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?",txt).group(0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a subtle problem with your script, which the following fixes:

```py
txt = "japan isn't 56 country in Europe."
nt = re.findall(r"n't [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9]?)?",txt)
print(nt)    # prints ["n't 56"]
```

In your original call to `re.findall`, you were using this pattern:

```
n't [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

This means that the first capture group is the optional term `.123`.  With the `re.findall` API, if you specify a capture group, then it is what will be returned.  Given that your input did *not* contain this group, your resulting list was empty.  In my corrected version, I made the capturing group *inactive*, using `?:`.  If you *don't* specify any explicit capture groups, then the entire matching pattern will be returned, which is the behavior you want here.

Comment: *I made the group optional, using `?:`* - no, you did not. With `(?:...)`, you made the capturing group [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions). Optional groups are made as such with `?` quantifier after them, ``(?:...)?`` or `(...)?`.

Answer (score 0):

`findall` is slightly weird when it comes to parentheses. Once you have them in there, it only returns the result of that group, not of the entire match. You can make the parentheses non-capturing:

```
>>> nt = re.findall(r"n't [0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9]?)?",txt)
>>> print(nt)
["n't 56"]
```